# How do I submit a javascript variable using a round trip to the server

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, submit

I have a string that I am building via javascript. For the purposes of this example:

```
var cereal = 'my super cereal string';
```

I have a button on the page:

```
<button id="save" type="submit" name="submit">Save</button>
```

How do I submit this string using a round trip (I do not want to use ajax).  I am using jquery in this application.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why don't you want to use AJAX?

Comment: +1 for having a concise example. So many people on SO paste in three pages of code and ask "what's wrong with this?"

Comment: micmcg, I want to proceed to the next page when I am done. (I know I could use 'on success' for this, but it doesn't seem appropriate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could assign a click listener to the `button` that builds up a throwaway `form` with an input containing your string:

```
var cereal = 'my super cereal string';
$("button#save").click(function() {
    var form = "<form id='hidden-form' style='display:none' method='POST' action='/echo/json'><input name='cereal' value='" + cereal + "' /></form>";

    $("body").append(form);
    $("form#hidden-form").submit();
});
```

Replacing the `form`'s `action` with whatever you want to POST to.

Check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/MNtwY/

Comment: @Aaron: input type is 'text' by default :) http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-type-INPUT

Answer (score 4):

not sure if it's the best or most elegant way, but you could have a form with a hidden field.  set the string to the hidden field, and then submit the form.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an option using a `GET` request:

```
var cereal = 'captain crunch';
$('#save').click(function () {
    window.location.href = "http://www.google.com/search?q=" + cereal;
});
```